gt() from gt colors cells w/ same content differently?
I am trying to make my table more intuitive by coloring the cells based on their content, hence gt(). However, cells with identical content are being colored differently, not even in the same color group. If any of you have suggestions on how to fix this, I would appreciate that a lot.
Picture for reference 
The desired outcome should have green for TRUE, black for FALSE, blue for "Upcoming" and red for "Missed"
I only used data_color(gt(df), col = c(5, 11)). I tried limiting the number of colors through palette = c("red", "blue", "green", "black") but it did not work either.

Please always include code for your data (at least a subset, or fake data simulating the same issues), the code you tried, the output you have, and the desired output. All as plain text, preferably not as rendered figures (although some illustrations of expected outputs in plots are ok)

@GuedesBF Thanks for the reminder, I was checking if this is data specific hence why I did not include these.

Using data_color you can specify a color-mapping function that will use col_*() functions from the scales package.
library(gt)

df <- data.frame(
  on_time_W2 = c("Missed visit", "Missed visit", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE"),
  on_time_W4 = "Missed visit",
  on_time_W6 = c("FALSE", "Missed visit", "FALSE", "Missed visit", "Missed visit"),
  on_time_W26 = c("TRUE", "Upcoming visit", "TRUE", "Upcoming visit", "Upcoming visit")
)

df |>
  gt() |>
  data_color(
    fn = scales::col_factor(
      palette = c("green", "black", "red", "blue"),
      levels = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "Missed visit", "Upcoming visit")
    ),
    apply_to = "fill"
  )

Table


Thanks, this is very helpful. Do you know why the initial outcome was like that? I used the same data_color(gt(df)) code for the other previous dataset and it did not produce any issue like this.

@Sum_Oan_Kewl Glad it was helpful. Not sure what has changed. I'm using package version gt_0.10.1 released in January. I believe data_color was significantly overhauled in version 0.9.0.
